# Tree Trunk on slope is floating on Unity Terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine, tree, terrain

I am using the Unity Standard Asset and have put some trees on my sloped terrain. When I do this, a part of the tree (the part which is lower on the slope) hangs a bit. I have a picture to display this. I have looked up some posts on this and most people say just to create your own tree in Unity Tree Editor and then adjust the offset. But the asset I am working with uses a 3d model imported in as a tree so I don't see any options for this. I have looked in the terrain settings to see if there is some sort of tree offset (which would be handy) but I can't find anything.

How do I get my trees to lay flush with the ground terrain?

Here is the image of what is happening:

[image]

Comment: What file type is the 3D model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the 3d model into an editor such as Blender and adjust the object origin

Comment: Thanks! I was overthinking this one for sure lol

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? Maybe through a script?

Comment: @Momoro, yes. If you wanted to do it strictly only though script, I believe you could get the mesh and subtract the same value from the y-value of every vert. If you just want to avoid blender another way may be to add a empty parent object to the tree and adjust the local y location of the tree downward.